# Does declaring enum value as ~0 generates a flag of one's (bitwise)?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, bitwise-operators

```
enum Test
{
    X = 1,
    Y = 1 << 1,
    Z = 1 << 2,
    All = ~0
}
```

Will `Test.All` be generated as a flag of bitwise one's, no matter how many values will be added to `Test` at a later points in time? For example, if new values are added:

```
enum Test
{
    X = 1,
    Y = 1 << 1,
    Z = 1 << 2,
    W = 1 << 3,
    WAndZ = W | Z,
    All = ~0
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `Test.All` will always include all the other values?

Comment: `All` will basically be equivalent to an integer with all bits set.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why not just use `-1`?

Comment: Aside: although having `None` as a label for no flags being set is useful, you almost certainly do not want an `All` flag that includes every possible value, even unallocated ones.This is because the meaning of `All` effectively changes with every new flag devised, for software that was never written to handle it.

Comment: @shay_ - yes it is guaranteed. But it's not 'a clever trick', it's sloppy programming.

Comment: @Rob - that's even worse.

Comment: Making `All` include flags that do not exist is questionable design.

Comment: @usr and Henk Holterman - I would agree, if the usage was for a "real" bitwise operations, but in my case it's just a flag that describes what operations should the called method execute. In a type safe environment such as C#, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @shay__ it works, no doubt about it. It's just a code smell. The Microsoft BCL would never allow that kind of imprecision in a public API for example. They have extreme standards, though.

Comment: The problem(s) are with readability, not with safety. That `WAndZ` is infinitely better

Comment: OK, thank you both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bitwise, this enum value will include all other values. This means tests like this:

```
(Test.All & Test.X) == Test.X
```

will evaluate to true to all members of this enum (even if integer value of `X` is `0`).

Likewise, you can (and should) have a default value for `0`, which will evaluate to false when matched against other flags:

```
enum Test
{
    None = 0,     // no flags
    X = 1,
    Y = 2,
    Z = 4,
    ...
    All = ~0      // all flags
}
```

This means `All` will include all flags, and `None` will include no flags:

```
Debug.Assert((Test.All & Test.None) == Test.None);
Debug.Assert((Test.All & Test.X) == Test.X);
Debug.Assert((Test.All & Test.All) == Test.All);

Debug.Assert((Test.None & Test.None) == Test.None);
Debug.Assert((Test.None & Test.X) == Test.None);
Debug.Assert((Test.None & Test.All) == Test.None);
```